# Web App to create website guided tours

Tags: web-applications

I am looking for a way to create a guided tour of a web app, much like youtube had when they did the redesign a while ago.

I am pretty sure I saw a web app that helped you create everything but cant seem to find it any more. I did find touration.com ( http://www.killerstartups.com/web-app-tools/touration-com-guide-your-visitors-through-your-site/ ) but that does not exist any more. Also found this script http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/comment-page-3/#comments which is what I might use if cant find this all in one website that does has it all set up for you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out the [Joyride jQuery plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) or [Optimizely's Guided.js](http://blog.optimizely.com/introducing-guidersjs-an-open-source-guider-e).

Comment: Awesome! Joyride is perfect, now that it can 'expose' the elements you're highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

Try [www.tourmyapp.com](http://www.tourmyapp.com) though its not free.

Answer (score 4):

[Chardin.js](http://heelhook.github.com/chardin.js/) is an interesting concept, although is fairly simple it does not have multiple steps. It reminds me of Gmail hints.

[Intro.js](http://usablica.github.com/intro.js/) is another popular one which has the possibility for multiple steps.